# Amazon Order History Reports not downloading

Tags: google-chrome

I've been trying to download Amazon's [Order History Reports](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201983330) to show my purchases during a date range. Unfortunately, the resulting report downloads are almost always empty (only 3 of 26 downloads had any data).

Would any other users have experienced this and have a resolution or work-around?

I've been using Chrome on Windows 10 but do have the same problem using Edge.

Comment: I don’t see anything indicating this is not a problem with Amazon. Contact Amazon.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, I think it's something on the Amazon side.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't help find who can resolve this problem. This morning, I successfully obtained a report for all of 2019.  Maybe they fixed the problem.

Comment: "that doesn't help find who can resolve this problem" - it doesn't? If it's a problem on the Amazon side, who do you think could resolve it other than Amazon? It seems pretty definitive to me.

Comment: I agree Amazon had to resolve the problem. I contacted Customer Service which agreed I had a problem but didn't accept responsibility to resolve it or tell me which Amazon group to contact for resolution. Given that I have now successfully downloaded the report for the whole year, the customer service representative may have contacted the responsible group which fixed the problem. In any event, the problem is now moot.